# Rotate div and have it displayed across entire screen

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have a div that I am wanting to rotate -20deg. I have gotten it to do just that, the problem I am facing is that it is **not displaying it across the whole screen**.

It is obviously just displaying a div that is  100% width and 100% height. What I am wanting it to do is cover the whole screen at an angle, so you can not see the left/right corners. If I extend the width above 100% it works but that is only going to push the width of the entire browser out.

Is there any way to get it to display at an angle so that it doesn't show the corners and is across the whole screen?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2dhkk03b/

```css
.content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 700px;
}
.intro {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.para_txt {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.intro p {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.slide {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="intro">
    <span>Hi there!</span>
    <p class="para_txt">My name</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slide"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element for the rotated rectangle and set overflow hidden on the parent div to hide the corners and prevent the bottom scrollbar :

```css
.content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 700px;
}
.intro {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.para_txt {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.intro p {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.slide {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide:after {
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  top:35%;
  width:100%; height: 30%;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="intro">
    <span>Hi there!</span>
    <p class="para_txt">My name</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slide">
</div>
```

Comment: that is getting a lot closer. is there a way to make it only hiude the overflow at the side of the browser, as its cutting it at the top.

Comment: @factordog yes, you will need to position the pseudo element absolutly (I editesd the code in the answer accordingly).

Comment: Right played with it a bit taking from the first answer and adapting it to your pseudo. I added a height to .slide:after of about 200% this then got the desired angle effect I was looking for. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah i see waht you did. Works a lot better than my solution. Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the corners of the div are square so if you rotate a rectangle x degrees you will lose some width.

The ideal solution would be to increase the size and minus the left margin for example.

```
width: 180%;
margin-left: -40%;
```

Thanks

Comment: that does make the issue a little less. However there is still the problem of it pushing out to the right with the extended width.

Comment: Wrap a div around it and add overflow hidden.